# 2 elements hover ISSUE jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

steps :

1. mousehover on big Image turns to grey - true
2. on click of button displaying FB Icon - true

but the Issue is **FB ICON Should NOT Turn to Grey**,  it has to keep its original color blue when ever mousehover is happening, 
I have written for mouseover but not sure why its not working.

Appreciate your help!!
Thanks!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/yzh477cn/)**

---

**JS :**

```
$(function(){
    gwt__features.init();
});
var social__hover__select       = $('.article_videos_item .article_videos_item_img'),
    social__sharing__icon       = $('.socialIconsWrap .social__sharing__icon'),
    social__sharing__content    = $('.social__sharing__content');


var gwt__features = ({
    social__hover : function(){
        $(social__hover__select).on('mouseover',function(){
            //$(social__sharing__icon).show();
            $(this).find('.social__sharing__icon').show();
        });
    },
    social__out : function(){
        $(social__hover__select).on('mouseout',function(){
            $(social__sharing__icon).hide();
            $(social__sharing__content).hide();
        });
    },
    social__click : function(){
        $(social__sharing__icon).on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(social__sharing__content).show();

            $(social__sharing__icon).on('mouseover',function(){
                //alert('asd');
                $(social__sharing__content).show();
            });
            $(social__sharing__content).on('mouseover',function(){
                console.log($(this));
                $(this).css ({
                    'border' : '1px solid #f00',
                    '-ms-filter' : 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)',
                    'filter' : 'none',
                    '-webkit-filter': 'none(100%)'                      
                })

            })
        });
    },
    init : function(){
        this.social__hover(),
        this.social__out(),
        this.social__click();
    }
});
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzh477cn/2). I had update css and js

```js
$(function() {
  gwt__features.init();
});
var social__hover__select = $('.article_videos_item .article_videos_item_img'),
  social__sharing__icon = $('.socialIconsWrap .social__sharing__icon'),
  social__sharing__content = $('.social__sharing__content');


var gwt__features = ({
  social__hover: function() {
    $(social__hover__select).on('mouseover', function() {
      //$(social__sharing__icon).show();
      $(this).find('.social__sharing__icon').show();
    });
  },
  social__out: function() {
    $(social__hover__select).on('mouseout', function() {
      $(social__sharing__icon).hide();
      $(social__sharing__content).hide();
    });
  },
  social__click: function() {
    $(social__sharing__icon).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(social__sharing__content).show();

      $(social__sharing__icon).on('mouseover', function() {
        //alert('asd');
        $(social__sharing__content).show();
      });
      /*$(social__sharing__content).on('mouseover',function(){
     console.log($(this));
     $(this).css ({
      'border' : '1px solid #f00',
      '-ms-filter' : 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)',
      'filter' : 'none',
      '-webkit-filter': 'none(100%)'      
     })
      
    })*/
    });
  },
  init: function() {
    this.social__hover(),
      this.social__out(),
      this.social__click();
  }
});
```

```css
.article_videos_item .article_videos_item_img {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.article_videos_item .gray-img:hover {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Fix for transition flickering */
}
.socialIconsWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.social__sharing__icon {
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.social__sharing__icon {
  background: #fff url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-share-48.png') no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
/*.social__sharing__icon:hover {
 background:url('social_sharing_40x40_hover.png') no-repeat;
}*/

.social__sharing__content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 38px;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.hide__greyout__social {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";
}
```

```html
<div class="article_videos_item clrfix">
  <div class="article_videos_item_img">
    <span class="field-content">
            <a href="/articles/nourish/75-percent-food-products-babies-and-toddlers-contain-too-much-ingredient">
                <img class="gray-img" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" width="340" height="226">
    <div class="socialIconsWrap">
     <div class="social__sharing__icon">
     
      <div class="social__sharing__content">
       <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/circle-facebook_-128.png" />
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
            </a>
         </span>
  </div>


</div>

<h4>
            original FB Icon Colour, should be same on hover, now its turning to grey with Big Image. 

BG Should be grey only, but not FB ICON.. :-(
    </br>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/circle-facebook_-128.png" />
    </h4>
```

Comment: Hey Kumar, tnx, but Background should be grey only it should not change

Comment: you mean when hover on this block background will not gray http://prntscr.com/6ekx5k

Comment: I had already post jsfiddle. 
change css http://prntscr.com/6el5p8
added class on img http://prntscr.com/6el5uw

Comment: Did you got something?